# How to see the list of channels user invited to

Tags: react-native, chat, getstream-io

We have a specific workflow for invite/reject/ban channels for users. 
1) I need to retrieve the list of channels user invited to, so that he can select some now and accept/reject it or do it later
2) When a user rejected invite - we need another query to be able to show such channel to a user, so that he can accept it. 
3) Push notification preferences, so that users can decide to receive or not push notification when he/she invited to a new channel.

I've checked docs https://getstream.io/chat/docs/#channel_invites, but the only covers how to send invites, and accept/reject. Nothing about how to display the list. And here https://getstream.io/chat/docs/#query_channels no pre-defined invites key for such cases.

As far as I can see, there is only one option so far: add a custom field for every invited person with. But it doesn't seem to be the right way to handle it

Comment: this is very good feedback, our dev team is adding support for this to the query channels so you get an update for this really soon

Comment: @TommasoBarbugli is there somewhere public-available timelines for new features? It seems that you have a lot on board, and we'd like to have a least some time estimations so that we can plan our own timelines for stream chat integration. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you use the query channels API endpoint we do not return channels with pending invitations.

You can query channels based on their invite status:

**Channels the user rejected:**

```
const invites = client.queryChannels({
    invite: 'rejected',
});
```

**Channels with a pending invitation:**

```
const invites = client.queryChannels({
    invite: 'pending',
});
```

Note: You can also combine the `invite` field in your query as you would normally do for any other channel field.